# Magento 1.9 -Two grids on the same page

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I have one **grid** on **my page**, but I want to make **another grid** on the same page.

Thanks

MagentoCommunityversion1.9

Comment: are you just displaying or you want it in magento admin form like in tab?